# Express js - how to redirect to new page with new data

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, routes

Im on the home page and i see a list of names. When I click a name, a post request is sent to the backend. From here, I want to one: load the respective profile data from the database, and two: redirect to the profile page and display that data.

From the research i've done, it seems like I have to create an http session variable and decorate that with my profile data before redirecting to the profile page. Is that the best way to go about this?

my html:

```
<div class="result" onclick="loadProfile(this)" onmouseover="showActions(this)" onmouseleave="removeActions(this)"> 
     <p id="user-id" style="display:none;"> 123456 </p>
     <div class="person-info">
              
     </div>  
</div>
```

my front-end js:

```
function loadProfile() {

}
```

how would i write the get request? and send the id as a param?

Comment: Please show us what you're putting in the POST operation.  You could just create a queryString URL and do a GET, not a POST since it sounds like all you're really doing is querying which should be a GET, not a POST.  Then, you just create a route that parses the profile criteria from the query parameters, does your  DB query and returns the results.  No session needed.

Comment: the request body will contain the id of the profile to load from the db. I get what you mean, but i dont just want to return the result to the home page, i want to load a new template

Comment: Yep, that should NOT be a POST.  You should just create a URL such as `/view?id=xxx`, make a route for `/view` and parse the query parameter - no session required, no redirect required - just a normal GET.  If you're doing this from a `<form>` without using client-side Javascript, you can change the form to make a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Querying data should be a GET request, not a POST request.  A POST would typically be for adding a new record or in some cases, modifying a record.  A GET is for querying existing data.  As such, you should be constructing a URL such as:

```
/profile?id=someName
```

And doing a GET request.  Then you create a route handler for `/profile` on your server (or whatever you want the URL to be named) and that route handler parses the `id` value out of the query string in the URL.  If you're using request, it would be in `req.query.id`.

Then, that route handler can use the id value to query the data store and show the appropriate profile page.

No session is needed.  No redirect is needed.  This is stateless (which is desirable from an http server point of view).  Note, this also creates a URL structure where a user can bookmark the profile page or you can link to it directly in HTML.

If you show the client-side HTML/code that is creating your current request, we could advise more specifically on how to create the GET request from it.  If you're using an HTML `<form>`, you can configure the form to create a GET request instead of the POST and to put the data into the query string.

In `loadProfile()`, you can just construct the URL by fetching the current ID based on the value of `this` and then just do in `loadProfile()`:

```
let id = <code to get id from the current HTML, based on the click>
let newURL = `/profile?id=${id}`;
window.location = newURL;    // will cause browser to go to that page
```

Then, construct the appropriate route on the server to handle this URL.

Comment: I've added some code to my post. Dont know how to write the get request. Should i be using XML?

Comment: @masterghani - See what I added to the end of my question.